# How to generate text from Python DataFrame

Tags: python

How do I generate a string of text based on data in a pandas dataframe?

```
for i in FLEDefendantsTbl:
doc.add_paragraph('At all times material hereto, ' + FLEDefendantsTbl['Name'] + ' was a Florida corporation that regularly transacted business in ' + CaseInfoTbl['County'] + ' County, Florida.')
```

I keep getting this error: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

I've already filtered exactly the table of data I want. I just need this text to be generated for each row of the filtered data. How do I do this?

Comment: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](//stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/843953)

Comment: You question is too ambiguous. Clearly specify your input, your expected output, and format your code for readability.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in FLEDefendantsTbl
```

will itterrate only through column names. To access the data and inject to string then

```
for index, row in FLEDefendantsTbl.iterrows():
    fstr = f'''At all times material hereto,  { row['Name']}  was a Florida corporation that regularly transacted business in {row['County']}  County, Florida.'''
    doc.add_paragraph(fstr)
```